# Longest path in directed graph cyclic graph where each node has one children

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

Consider given directed unweighted cyclic graph with $N$ nodes, and $N$ edges, and each node has at most one out-going children. Find the longest path.

**Example**

Consider the following graph, the path $2, 3, 1$ is the longest covering all 3 nodes.

[image: Example]

**What I think for the solution**

Because every node has at most one children we form some type of equation that for node $a$, and it's children $b$, the path starting from node $a$ = path to start from $b + 1$, but I think because there are cycles this wont work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'longest path'?  If the graph has cycles, there is no longer path -- for any path you have in mind, I can find one that is even longer (by traversing the cycle as many times as needed until my path is longer than yours).  Did you mean the longest *simple* path?

Answer (score 1):

As *rus9384* & you seemed to have figured out in the comments, there exists an $O(N)$ solution to the problem.

First, apply the well known algorithm to find [Strongly Connected Components](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strongly-connected-components/) in the graph in $O(N)$. Then, after collapsing all such components into single nodes, you can slightly modify the algorithm to find the [Longest Path in a DAG](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/) to get your answer in $O(N)$ time.